# Complications regarding use of 'by then'

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> When I was last there, he hadn't arrived by then.

Should 'by then' be used if a sentence already has 'when'? And if it can't be used, then what would be the correct structure of the sentence?

Comment: Do you mean "By the time I left, he hadn't arrived"?

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of grammar, it doesn't make logical sense. *Then* has to refer to a specific time.

> I last checked at five o'clock, and he hadn't arrived by then.

...but we can say

> When I was last there, he hadn't arrived yet/ he still hadn't arrived.

Comment: "Then" refers to "when I was last there". Makes logical sense to me, even if it's not great otherwise